# Pull All Rows that Contain Same Invoice Number if Cell contains value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with 7000 rows.  Each row contains products that were purchased.  If a purchase has 5 items then the invoice number will be listed 5 times in column a.  In column P i have a True / False expression if column H contains a value (vzprotect).  What I am trying to do is if column H = true then to pull all rows for that invoice onto sheet2.

Column P

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("vzprotect",H6981))
```

Sample Data

```
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZRB000799        Installment Service Fee                             FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZNS000800        Installment Amount / 24 Months                              FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZNS000066        New Activation Rate Plan                                FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZRB000069        Rate Plan SKU                               FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZRB000798        Installment Rebate Amount                               FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZRB000992        TMP New Manual                              FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZRB001517        DPNiPhone                               FALSE
NANDOIN7112 N Andover MA    John Smith  Aug 14, 2019 11:59 AM   robert keohane  CLVZVZ001054        APPLE IPHONE 8 64GB SILVER MQ732LL/A                                FALSE
```

Data with True in column P

```
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Installment Service Fee                             FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Installment Amount / 24 Months                              FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Upgrade Rate Plan                               FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            New Activation Rate Plan                                FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Rate Plan SKU                               FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Rate Plan SKU                               FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            2 Year New Activation Jetpack                               FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            DPUAndroid                              FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Installment Rebate Amount                               FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            installment Contract Number                             FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            TMP Commission Tracker                              FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            Decline Insurance-66332                             FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            87165 - VZProtect Smartphones T1 and Watches                                TRUE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            VZW ELLIPSIS JETPACK MHS900L                                FALSE
NANDOIN7116 N Andover MA    Frank Sinatra   Aug 15, 2019 12:32 PM   Adam Sandler            SAMSUNG GALAXY S10E 128GB PRISM BLACK SMG970UZKV                                FALSE
```

I removed a bunch of columns that contain confidential information.

Comment: What approach do you want to use? Formulas? VBA? Post what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Power Query. Conceptually:

- Load the data into Power query, delete all columns except for the Invoice number and the column H.
- filter by the column H = True
- save as a connection
- Load the data into Power Query again
- do a join with the first query, using the Invoice number as the matching column and using the "left outer" join kind
- expand the joined table and keep the column H true values, which will be applied to all rows with the matching invoice numbers
- filter by the column H = True values
- remove the helper columns
- save and load the query into a worksheet.

When the original data gets changed, refresh the query. All without writing code or formulas, just clicking icons. The screenshot shows the result table in green. my "column H" is called "keep".

[image]

Comment: I would also suggest using Power Query but I would remove Column P from the source data, load the original data to the editor and create a duplicate query, in the original query, do the filter of `vzprotect` directly in Column H, then remove other columns except the Invoice Number column and then remove duplicated invoice numbers. Then in the duplicated query do a merge with the first query, and then expand the table and filter out null, what's left should be what @DavidMorin looking for.

Comment: @TerryW, there are a dozen different ways. Yours is very similar to mine, nothing dramatically different, really. The core principle is to come up with two lists, one identifying the records that are to be kept in the other.

Comment: This worked great for my needs.  Thank you @teylyn  I was able to get all the data I needed.